# write (add) multiple array in firestore

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

[image]I try to add multiple array in firestore using struct codable in swiftui but when I add, it updates the same array added but i want add more array in my list...

as you can see in the image, every time I add a text, it updates my index "0" but I want to add multiple indexes, for example O, 1, 2... in my array" tags"

***ViewModel***

```
class DataManager: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var books = Book(tags: [Tag(title: "", color: "")])
    
    func addBookNew(nom: String, prenom: String){
        //guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let collectionRef = db.collection("Users").document("TEST")

          do {
              let data = Book(tags: [Tag(title: nom, color: prenom)])
              try collectionRef.setData(from: data)


          }
          catch {
            print(error)
          }
        
    }
```

***STRUCT BOOK***

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct Book: Codable {
    
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    let tags: [Tag]
 
}
```

***STRUCT TAG***

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct Tag: Codable, Hashable {
  let title: String
  let color: String
}
```

***LIST VIEW***

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct ListView: View {
    
    @StateObject var dataManager = DataManager()
    @State private var showPopUp = false
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AppViewModel
    var books: [Book]
    
    
    @State var nomTF = ""
    @State var prenomTF = ""
    @State var dismiss = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                TextField("nom", text: $nomTF )
                TextField("prenom", text: $prenomTF)
                Button("save") {
                    dataManager.addBookNew(nom: nomTF, prenom: prenomTF)
                }
                List{
                    ForEach(dataManager.books.tags, id: \.self) { book in
                        HStack{
                            Text("T: \(book.title)")
                            Text("C: \(book.color)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.onAppear(){
                dataManager.fetchtest()
            }
```

Comment: Why did you tag this with [tag:google-maps]?

Comment: sorry it was an error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
let data = Book(tags: [Tag(title: nom, color: prenom)])
try collectionRef.setData(from: data)
```

This code tells Firestore to **set** the `tags` field to the array that you specify in the call.

If you want to [add unique items to existing array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array), you can use `FieldValue.arrayUnion([...])`.

```
let data = Book(tags: FieldValue.arrayUnion([Tag(title: nom, color: prenom)]))
try collectionRef.setData(from: data)
```

Note that this will only add the item if it is not already in the array. If you want to allow for duplicate items, you will have to read the array from the document first, then updates in your application code, and finally write the entire array back to the database.

---

**Update**: it seems your `Book` class can only accept `Tag` in its `tags` field, so you can't specify an `FieldValue.arrayUnion` there. It's probably easiest to then simply perform the union in the database call:

```
try collectionRef.updateData([
  "tags": FieldValue.arrayUnion([Tag(title: nom, color: prenom)])
])
```

So instead of writing the entire book here, we're [updating a single field in the document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data), and in there perform the array union.

```
washingtonRef.updateData([
    "regions": FieldValue.arrayUnion(["greater_virginia"])
])
```

Comment: thank you for your quick reply,
I tried your solution but I get an error
"Cannot convert value of type 'FieldValue' to expected argument type '[Tag]'"

Comment: First off: did the explanation I gave of why you're getting the result that you get make sense though? That is important, and going forward I recommend acknowledging that (if it is), so that we have an improved ground to work from. --- It seems like your `Book` class can only accept `Tag `in its tags field, so you can't specify an `FieldValue.arrayUnion` there.  Since you want to perform a partial update to the document, using a full `Book` might not make the most sense. I updated my answer to show how to update a single field without using your `Book` class.

Comment: i get another error  with your update solution is :  "No calls to throwing functions occur within 'try' expression" AND "'catch' block is unreachable because no errors are thrown in 'do' block"

Comment: That seems like a completely different problem. Did you search for that error message already, as I can imagine that this one has probably been covered in the past.

Comment: just an idea, i don't have the pod file in the project, but i added swift package "firebase"... from add package in xcode, do you think the error can come from there?...and where can I put this do {
          let book = Book(title: "The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy",
                          author: "Douglas Adams")
          let encode = JSONEncoder()
          let data = try encoder.encode(book)
        }
        catch {
          print("Error when trying to encode book: \(error)")
        }


can if I integrate this it could work no?

Comment: Sorry, but that's all really broad and not really my area of expertise. I explained why your code overwrites the entire document and how to add an item to an array, which seemed to be what you said in the first paragraph of your question. Does the explanation I give on why you're seeing that behavior make sense? Does it also make sense how `arrayUnion` would help you implement it?